# Python how to store "\" inside an arrey to use in a subprocess.call bash command

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

i have a python program that creates a bash command and then uses it in subprocess.call(command)

i wand to send it a file location with spaces.

```
import subprocess
command = ["mkdir","/home/matt/Desktop/this"]
command[1] +=  "\\ is"
subprocess.call(command)
```

but when it is used by subprocess it becomes a new directory with the name
 this\ is

this is the full code

```
import pyxhook
import subprocess

command = [""]
isActive = False
element = 0
isSpace = False

def OnKeyPress(event):
    global command
    global isActive
    global element
    global isSpace
    if event.Ascii == 96:
        if isActive == False:
            isActive = True
        elif isActive == True:
            subprocess.call(command)
            command = [""]
            element = 0
            isActive = False
    elif isActive == True:
        if event.Ascii == 32:
            if isSpace == False:
                command.append("")
                element += 1
            else:
                command[element] += " "
                isSpace = False
        elif event.Key == "BackSpace":
            command[element] = command[element][:-1]
        elif event.Key == "slash":
            command[element] += "/"
        elif event.Key == "Shift_L" :
            command = command
        elif event.Key =="Shift_R":
            command = command
        elif event.Key == "backslash":
            isSpace = True
            command[element] +=  "\\"
        else:
            command[element] += (event.Key)

#instantiate HookManager class
new_hook=pyxhook.HookManager()
#listen to all keystrokes
new_hook.KeyDown=OnKeyPress
#hook the keyboard
new_hook.HookKeyboard()
#start the session
new_hook.start()
```

Comment: @smarx it will run. String will be implicitly converted to list of characters. It will be then extended with the list.

Comment: i edited my post to reflect those issues and posted my full code

Comment: You don't need to escape anything, because `command` isn't being processed by the shell. The string value is passed directly to `execve` (or one of the `exec`s, anyway) as one argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
path = "/home/matt/Desktop/this"
path += " is"
os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)
```

If your Python is older than 3.2, remove `exist_ok=True`.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to your command list and how you're appending things:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> command = ["mkdir", "/home/matt/Desktop/this"]
>>> command[0] +=  "\\ is"
>>> command
['mkdir\\ is', '/home/matt/Desktop/this']
>>> command = ["mkdir", "/home/matt/Desktop/this"]
>>> command[-1]
'/home/matt/Desktop/this'
>>> command[-1] += " is"
>>> command
['mkdir', '/home/matt/Desktop/this is']
>>> subprocess.call(command)
0
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob("/home/matt/Desktop/th*")
['/home/matt/Desktop/this is']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for helping

```
import subprocess
command = ["mkdir","/home/matt/Desktop/this"]
command[1] +=  " is"
subprocess.call(command)
```

you don't need to use \ when using subprocess